# React duplicate API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am making a fetch request to an API, the request is successful but when I `console.log` the response it gets logged twice.

My component:

```js
const Content = () => {
  let userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/post/`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + userId.token,
      },
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      }
    );
    
  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <Name></Name>
        <Time></Time>
        <Image></Image>
        <Text></Text>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The console would log:

> (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Why would I get two responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call fetch on every render. use useEffect hook to prevent it.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/post/`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + userId.token,
      },
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      }
    );
}, []);
```

In other case you might have two or more  component.
to prevent fetch twice and access one for all. I recommend to use react-query.
You can just

```
useQuery('data', fetch())
```